# modify font size on y axis for Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

When I try to modify my y axis title, it just disapears. Modifying the y axis ticks works just fine. Has anyone had this problem? Thanks!

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(2017)
x <- seq(1:10)
y <- x + rnorm(10)
plot_ly( x = ~x, y = ~y + rnorm(10)) %>%
     layout(
       xaxis = list(tickfont = list(size = 15)), 
       yaxis = list(tickfont = list(size = 25))) ## This works well.

 plot_ly( x = ~x, y = ~y + rnorm(10)) %>%
     layout(
       xaxis = list(tickfont = list(size = 15)), 
       yaxis = list(titlefont = list(size = 25))) ## This makes the y axis label disappear.
```

The goal is to modify the size of the y axis title, not to make it disappear all together.

Comment: I'm not getting an error but I am getting a message( actually two such)  that suggest you are not passing arguments correctly: `No trace type specified:
  Based on info supplied, a 'scatter' trace seems appropriate.
  Read more about this trace type -> https://plot.ly/r/reference/#scatter`. You SHOULD edit your question to include any messages, and if you are not getting this message, then you should post all your system details.

Comment: @ 42, thank you. I updated the code , type and mode. the yaxis title still disappears if the titlefont variable is set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that it those cases it is necessary to also specify the title itself:

```
plot_ly( x = ~x, y = ~y + rnorm(10)) %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(tickfont = list(size = 15)), 
    yaxis = list(titlefont = list(size = 25), title = "test"))
```

[image]

Comment: @ Julius, thank you! In my real work there are multiple charts with the y axis title coming from the variable name, so it doesn't make sense to name it explicitly. Is it possible to use something like title = to the y variable name?

Comment: @Joe, I guess you could do `title = deparse(substitute(y)))`, where `y` is your variable.

Comment: @ Julius, Gracias!!

Answer (score 7):

In case someone is looking for similar answer for python.
You can add `fig.update_yaxes(title_font=dict(size=12))`